# MinGW and XAML/WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, mingw

Is it possible to use WPF (and XAML) with MinGW? Is there a tutorial with a sample project somewhere? What libraries do I have to link against and are the WPF headers available in a way that enables using it with MinGW?

(I want to do this for fun; for a real project I'd obviously use VS)

I'd prefer a plain C example (using COM, since I assume this is required), but would also consider a C++ example.

Answer (score 0):

I would think not since WPF is a part of the .Net Framework and is used with the CLR whilst MinGW compiles code to native, unmanaged, win32 binaries.  You're not going to be able to 'include' WPF assemblies into a MinGW build.

I think you could possibly use MinGW to compile an unmanaged C++ component (dll) and then use that in a managed (C#) WPF program.